# Is there a quick way to fix line ending problems in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, formatting, settings

I am looking at a project which contains a mix of source files - built on a variety of systems. When I attempt to compile it, I'm getting some errors from the pre-processor which suggest that my line ending formatting mix is just not cutting it.

Is there a quick way to correct this in Xcode? I'm looking to globally change the line ending format in all of my files, save, and recompile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an xcode way of doing it but you could fix it with sed.

```
ls *.c | sed 's/.$//';
```

You probably need to do this on an entire project, an utility like [flip](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~craig/utility/flip/) might work out better. You can get the source from the website.